# Destroy Parent Object Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, parent-child, unityscript, destroy

I'm facing the problem that i wish to destroy a parent object but i couldn't do so.

i wish to destroy User01 while bullet hit any of these child.

My code was as below.

JS:

function OnControllerColliderHit(col:ControllerColliderHit){

```
if(col.gameObject.tag == "Bullet"){

    Destroy(col.transform.parent.gameObject);

}
```

}

C#:

public class PlayerDoe : MonoBehaviour {

```
private  GameObject par;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

    par = transform.parent.gameObject;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}

void OnCollisionHit(Collision col){

            if (col.gameObject.tag == "Bullet") {
                Destroy(par);
            }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to use OnCollisionEnter, instead of OnCollisionHit.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `OnCollisionHit()`. You want to use [**OnCollisionEnter**](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html)

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if(col.gameObject.tag == "Bullet")
       Destroy(transform.parent.gameObject);      
}
```